# Get HashTags with facebook connect

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, hashtag

I've made a very simple new app on Facebook. Then I used Facebook connect to connect on a website, and I want to get some `hashtag`.

But I don't figure how to get them using facebook connect?

Eg : I want to get the content of: https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/learntocode, which can be only displayed if connected onto facebook.

Any ideas to get the content of this page while connected with Facebook Connect? I can't find any documentation on that issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no public API to retrieve/search hash tags, as far as I am aware. You can use the standard Search API but it doesn't specifically search for hashtags (i.e. a search for "#Facebook" will return posts with the word "Facebook" in and not specifically ones with that hash tag).

Comment: Are you sure that theres no public api for that ? It seems weird

Comment: @sophiaa Yeah I'm pretty sure, Facebook often take a little while to push out new features to their public APIs.